# jQuery "or if" statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-validate

I have the function that checks if a container has invalid form fields. If it has then to the link, which is showing particular container, 'hasErrors' class is being added.

```
function treatFormLinks () {
    if (!$('#One .required').valid() ) {
        $('#LinkOne').addClass('hasErrors');    
    }
    if (!$('#Two .required').valid() ) {
        $('#LinkTwo').addClass('hasErrors');    
    }
    if (!$('#Three .required').valid() ) {
        $('#LinkThree').addClass('hasErrors');  
    }
};

$("#Submit").click(function () {
    treatFormLinks();
});
```

It works fine but problem appears if container #Two fields are valid but container #Three fields have some errors. In this case 'hasErrors' class is not added to #LinkThree.

I understand that there is problem in the logic in this function, but how would I say browser to keep checking those containers until they all are checked.

Stupid problem, I know, but need help anyway :)

Comment: I'm using jQuery Validation Plugin, if it matters.

Comment: Your code should work as-is, as long as your form isn't actually submitting due to not returning false.

Comment: From what you've shown us, it should do what you are asking.  There's nothing in the above that will stop it validating further elements, regardless of outcome.

Comment: The code looks OK to me, too.  Check your HTML attributes for elements that are supposed to match `#Three`, `.required`, and `#LinkThree`.

Comment: Did you call `$('#LinkThree').validate()` before this? `valid()` only works if the form has been registered with `validate()` first.

Comment: @Barmar yes form is registered.

Comment: @KevinB, @Archer, Thanks for your answers. I'll explain a bit more. Lets say, `#One` has erors, `#Two` doesn't and `#Three` has. According to current logic `.hasErrors` will not be added to `#LinkThree`, because `#Two` is passing validation. How could I say in this function "or if"?

Comment: In your current logic, it will be added to LinkThree as well.

Comment: @KevinB but it's not. The function is not completed till the end if `#Two` is valid. But if it's not then I see the result I expect - all the links are marked with `.hasError`

Comment: @MityaUstinov Are you absolutely sure the code in the question is identical to the code you are using, and the code you are using doesn't have a coding error at that location?

Comment: @Kevin This function stops after the first "if" condition is true. If `#One` is invalid, `#Two` is valid and `#Three` is invalid `#LinkThree`  looks like valid anyway, because function is not running further since `#Two` has no errors. How can I make it working till the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my mistake was not obvious at all and here's how I fixed this. I replaced

```
!$('#One .required').valid()
```

with this

```
!$('#One input, #One select, #One textarea').valid()
```

in each case and now it's working as I expected.

Comment: And everyone of you, guys, was right basing on the information you had. Thank you all!